# Can a live wallpaper also be an application? (With a separate Activity for the Application)

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have a Live Wallpaper which I would like to also make available as an Activity which can be accessed as a normal Phone App.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append an acitivity with

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

in the manifest. You can have as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can you just need to setup the activities you want to expose through proper intent filters in your Android manifest under the application node..

```
<activity ...> <!-- this being the activity you want to expose -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```